Efficient access to data in a series of transient Python scripts
Pandoc has a filter that accepts Python snippets and uses (for example) Matplotlib to generate charts. I want to produce documents that produce many charts from a common data source (e.g. a pandas data frame).
As an example:
Here's the first chart:

~~~{.matplotlib}
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

conn = sqlite3.connect('somedb.db')
query = '''SELECT something'''

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn).dropna()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.something()
~~~

The problem is that every chart has to regenerate the data frame, which is expensive. What I'd like to do is:

Run a script at the beginning of the Markdown document that creates the data source and makes it available efficiently to subsequent filter calls.
Use the data to create as many charts as I need from the existing data source.
Shut down the data source with the pandoc call ends (or maybe with a time-to-live parameter).

Any ideas?

The author of pandoc-plot kindly provided the following answer in Github:
Out-of-the-box there's no handling of your use-case in the pandoc-plot filter. Each code block that gets turned into a plot is intended to be independent from all others. This has many benefits, most importantly performance -- I wrote pandoc-plot for book-sized workloads, with close to 100 figures.
The reason using preamble isn't working is because the preamble script gets copy-pasted into every code block before pandoc-plot renders a figure. Therefore, the creation of your dataframe will still be duplicated.
I would recommend you proceed with a script to wrap your usage of pandoc. For example (assuming you use bash):
# Run a script that goes through your expensive computation,
# storing the results as a CSV i
python create-data.py

# Render the document, where plots can reference the file created by 
# your python script instead of re-creating the pandas dataframe for every plot
pandoc -f pandoc-plot ...

# Clean up temporary data file if you know where it is

You can communicate between the bash script above and your document plots using environment variables.
